# How to create .lnk file to Network-Folder

Tags: delphi, networking, directory

I am currently trying to generate a link-file to a Folder on a mounted Network drive. I searched the MS-documentations about the IShellLink object, but I don't really know what else to try.

I managed to create lnk-Files to Files/Folders on the current System, as well as links to Files on mapped Network drives using the following code:

```
function GenerateLink(ATarget, ASaveTarget: string): boolean;
var
  IObject: IUnknown;
  ISLink: IShellLink;
  IPFile: IPersistFile;

  ShellFolder: IShellFolder;
  BindContext: IBindCtx;
  FileSystem: IFileSystemBindData;

  chEaten: Cardinal;
  dwAttributes: Cardinal;
  PIDL: PItemIDList;
begin
  Result := false;

  CoInitialize(nil);

  IObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
  FileSystem := TFileSystemBindData.Create;

  ISLink := IObject as IShellLink;
  IPFile := IObject as IPersistFile;

  SHGetDesktopFolder(ShellFolder);
  CreateBindCtx(0, BindContext);
  BindContext.RegisterObjectParam(STR_FILE_SYS_BIND_DATA, FileSystem);
  ShellFolder.ParseDisplayName(0, Pointer(BindContext), pChar(ATarget), chEaten, PIDL,
    dwAttributes);

  if Assigned(PIDL) then
    ISLink.SetIDList(PIDL)
  else
    exit;

  IPFile.Save(PWideChar(ASaveTarget), false);
  Result := true;
end;
```

This code works well as said with files, no matter where they are located, but not for Folders. 
There I went with this approach:

```
function GenerateFolderLink(ATarget, ASaveTarget: String): boolean;
var
  IObject: IUnknown;
  ISLink: IShellLink;
  IPFile: IPersistFile;
begin
  Result := false;
  CoInitialize(nil);
  IObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
  ISLink := IObject as IShellLink;
  IPFile := IObject as IPersistFile;

  with ISLink do
  begin
    SetPath(pChar(ATarget));
    SetWorkingDirectory(pChar(ExtractFilePath(ATarget)));
  end;

  IPFile.Save(PWideChar(ASaveTarget), false);

  Result := true;
end;
```

This works perfectly for all local folders.

Only missing piece are folders on mapped Network drives. While the Links to "X:\" work, links to specific Folders are broken ("X:\TEST")

Thanks for your Input ;)

Update: I just found out, that using the UNC-Path the Links will work as well, so my problem only relates to mapped drives.

Comment: o_O. Create ini file with InternetShortcut section and write UNC path to URL string parametr, like \\SUPERFRIEND\SHARED_FOLDER_ON_OTHER_PC_SOMEWHERE_IN_THE_NETWORK Save filewith *.url extension

Comment: URL-Files are not an Option. The lnk-file is created on an own web-Service and sent to Clients (in same Network). But due to some IE-Settings it is not guaranteed that every Client can open those .URL files.

Comment: Solution for the problem is: 

Application running on System privileges had no Access to the users network-drives. Adding the needed "net use" commands fixed that Problem.

But is there perhaps any way (like in the source for the file-links) that the Server does not Need knowledge of the files he is linking? I would like to use this without the net-use stuff on system-Level...

Comment: Well, you should have told us that you were running as a user that did not have the drives mapped!

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Yes, service application and therefor requiring the mapping on system level using the second way. Unfortunately the first code i posted (that one works without mappings) does - as far as i can say - not support folder-links.